# Types of parameters 'a' and 'left' are incompatible

Tags: typescript, generics

I am a new TypeScript user so please bear with me

### ⚽ The Goal

I am trying to create a method that returns a MinHeap (Priority Queue) by accepting an array of `number | string | object` and optionally a compare function (kind of like the one for [Array.sort](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort#Syntax)).

⩴⩴⩴⩴⩴⩴⩴⩴⩴⩴

### Code in Question

*A demo available on [Repl.it](https://repl.it/@dance2die/callback-type-inference).*

`useHeap` below accepts an generic array type and the optional `comp` comparor also accepts the type parameter.

```js
function isNumberArray(o: any[]): o is number[] {
  return o.every(n => typeof n === "number");
}
function isStringArray(o: any[]): o is string[] {
  return o.every(n => typeof n === "string");
}

// type Unpack<T> = T extends (infer R)[] ? R : T;
interface Comparor<T> {
  (left: T, right: T): number;
}

function useHeap<T>(args: T[], comp?: Comparor<T>): T[] {
  if (!comp) {
    if (isStringArray(args)) {
      comp = (a, b) => a < b ? -1 : a > b ? 1 : 0;
      console.log(`args is an STRING array!`, ...args, comp);
    } else if (isNumberArray(args)) {
      console.log(`args is a NUMBER array!`, ...args, comp);
    } else {
      // throw new Error("You need to pass a comparor for an object array");
      console.log(`args is an OBJECT array!`, ...args, comp);
    }
  } else {
    console.log(` comp available!`, ...args, comp);
  }

  // turn the T[] into a heap using the Comparor

  return [] as T[];
}
```

⩴⩴⩴⩴⩴⩴⩴⩴⩴⩴

### ‍♂️ Issues

When I call the `useHeap` like following,

```js
useHeap([1, 2, 3]);
useHeap([1, 2, 3], (a, b) => a * b);
useHeap(["c1", "a1", "b1"]);
useHeap(["c", "a", "b"], (a, b) => a < b ? -1 : a > b ? 1 : 0);
useHeap([{ id: 1, weight: 10 }, { id: 2, weight: 20 }]);
useHeap([{ id: 1, weight: 10 }, { id: 2, weight: 20 }], (a, b) => a.weight - b.weight);
```

following is printed in the console.

```sh
TypeScript v3.3.3 linux/amd64
args is a NUMBER array! 1 2 3 undefined
 comp available! 1 2 3 (a, b) => a * b
args is an STRING array! c1 a1 b1 (a, b) => a < b ? -1 : a > b ? 1 : 0
 comp available! c a b (a, b) => a < b ? -1 : a > b ? 1 : 0
args is an OBJECT array! { id: 1, weight: 10 } { id: 2, weight: 20 } undefined
 comp available! { id: 1, weight: 10 } { id: 2, weight: 20 } (a, b) => a.weight - b.weight
```

The problem is when I try to assign a default comparor for an array of type number.

```
function useHeap<T>(args: T[], comp?: Comparor<T>): T[] {
  if (!comp) {
    if (isStringArray(args)) {
      comp = (a, b) => a < b ? -1 : a > b ? 1 : 0;
      console.log(`args is an STRING array!`, ...args, comp);
    } else if (isNumberArray(args)) {
      //  These throw an error
+      comp = (a, b) => a - b;
+      comp = (a: number, b: number) => a - b;
      console.log(`args is a NUMBER array!`, ...args, comp);
    } else {
    }
  } else {
    console.log(` comp available!`, ...args, comp);
  }

  // turn the T[] into a heap using the Comparor

  return [] as T[];
}
```

#### 1st attempt

Hovering over `comp = (a, b) => a - b` shows,

> [typescript] The left-hand side of an arithmetic operation must be of type 'any', 'number', 'bigint' or an enum type.
>
> (parameter) a: T

[image: first error]

#### 2nd attempt

while `comp = (a: number, b: number) => a - b;` shows

> [typescript]
>   Type '(a: number, b: number) => number' is not assignable to type 'Comparor'.
>     Types of parameters 'a' and 'left' are incompatible.
>       Type 'T' is not assignable to type 'number'.
>   (parameter) comp: Comparor | undefined

[image: second error]

⩴⩴⩴⩴⩴⩴⩴⩴⩴⩴

### Main Questions

1. Why is the number recognized even though `if (isNumberArray(args))` passed?
2. How can I make the `comp`'s type to be recognized correctly?

### Additional Context

Please don't hesitate to let me know how I can write it in more TypeScript-like

Comment: First off, I've rarely seen someone go through this much effort to format a question nicely. Bravo! Second, you're mixing generics and run-time type checking, which is *generally* bad style. You've checked that values numbers, but not that `T` extends `number` (e.g. consider `useHeap<number|string>([1,2,3])`)

Comment: Thank you @p.s.w.g . I never realized that `T` constraint is a compile time check while the `is...Array` are runtime checks & mixing them are bad.  Let me constraint the `T` and try again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd say this is not a great solution. It's generally bad practice to use run-time type checking within a generic method (the whole point of a "generic" method is that the logic should work for any type provided). But here's a more type-friendly solution to get you past your current issue:

```
const stringComparer = <T extends string>(a: T, b: T) => a < b ? -1 : a > b ? 1 : 0;
const numberComparer = <T extends number>(a: T, b: T) => a - b;
function getDefaultComparitor<T>(args: T[]): Comparor<T> | undefined {
    if (isStringArray(args)) {
      return stringComparer as Comparor<T>;
    } else if (isNumberArray(args)) {
      return numberComparer as Comparor<T>;
    }

    return undefined;
}

function useHeap<T>(args: T[], comp?: Comparor<T>): T[] {
  if (!comp) {
    comp = getDefaultComparitor(args);
    if (!comp) {
      console.log(` unable to determine default comparitor!`, ...args);
    }
  } else {
    console.log(` comp available!`, ...args, comp);
  }

  // turn the T[] into a heap using the Comparor
  return [] as T[];
}
```

Note: the `as Comparer<T>` is code smell and should be alerting you that something's wonky here.

A somewhat nicer solution would be to use overloads to provide errors at compile-time:

```
function useHeap(args: string[]);
function useHeap(args: number[]);
function useHeap<T>(args: T[], comp: Comparor<T>);
function useHeap<T>(args: T[], comp?: Comparor<T>) {
  // same as above
}
```

Now, this test case will generate an error:

```
useHeap([{ id: 1, weight: 10 }, { id: 2, weight: 20 }]);
```

> Type '`{ id: number; weight: number; }`' is not assignable to type '`number`'.

Which is not an extremely informative error message, but at least it can be caught earlier. You can improve the error message by with some more subtle overloads like this:

```
type ComparitorParameter<T> = T extends string|number ? []|[Comparor<T>] : [Comparor<T>];

function useHeap<T>(args: T[], ...comp:ComparitorParameter<T>);
function useHeap<T>(args: T[], comp?: Comparor<T>): T[] {
  // same as above
}
```

The invalid test case will now generate a much more intuitive error:

> Expected 2 arguments, but got 1.

Comment: Thank you again for how the code can be improved (& ""  ).  I am having a bit trouble grokking `ComparitorParameter<T>` and the need to spread  like`...comp:ComparitorParameter<T>`. (FYI - I tried the code above in a forked repl https://repl.it/@dance2die/callback-type-inference-1)

Comment: @SungM.Kim I first tried `ComparitorParameter<T> = T extends string|number ? undefined|Comparor<T> : Comparor<T>` but it still required you to specify a second parameter for `useHeap([1,2,3])`, so instead, for `string|number` I allow for a possibly empty array. You could also use `ComparitorParam<T> = Parameters<(T extends number|string ? (comp?: Comparator<T>)=>0 : (comp: Comparator<T>)=>0)>`, but that seems more confusing and kludgey (at least in my opinion), so I didn't bring it up in the answer.

Comment: Wow  That's the what the `[]|[Comparor<T>]` was for. An optional `string|number` comparor. Thank you for the explanations there. 